# smtlib mail does not send and no error code

Tags: python, email, smtplib, email-client

I want to send a mail from within a script if the comparison of two files fails.

(The script monitors a website and stores a sample of that page as log file and compares each day
to the last day version and sends a mail in case something changes)

I have the following code snippet and it works fine and sends the mail.

(Of course I have replaced my actual credentials with samples here, but the code works with my credentials entered)

The sample code (working):

```
import smtplib

sender = "Sender <sender@example.com>"
receiver = "Receiver <receiver@example.com>"

message = f"""\
Subject: test notification mail
To: {receiver}
From: {sender}

This is a test e-mail notification."""

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.example.com", 2525) as server:
    server.login("username", "password")
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
```

However, when I insert that code snippet into the main code, it seems to run through without errors, but no mail is sent...

The actual code (mail not working):

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import difflib
import filecmp
import smtplib


class App():

    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            # url to monitor
            url = 'https://www.website.com'
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'}

            # download the webpage
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            # parse the downloaded webpage and grab all text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
            # find the class that contains all new id document entries, get the text and get rid of html expressions
            self.soup_class = soup.find(class_='row').text.strip()

            self.last_check = '2021-09-21'
            last_check_file = 'Log' + '_' + self.last_check + '.txt'

            while True:
                # create new current check file
                new_check_file = self.create_log_file()
                if filecmp.cmp(last_check_file, new_check_file, shallow=False):
                    print('No changes found', self.get_date(), self.get_time())
                else:
                    print('Changes detected: ' + self.get_date())
                    file1 = open(last_check_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
                    file2 = open(new_check_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
                    for line in difflib.unified_diff(file1, file2, fromfile='file1', tofile='file2', lineterm='', n=0):
                        print(line)

                    # send notification mail
                    self.send_mail()

                self.last_check = self.get_date()
                # wait 24h for next check
                time.sleep(86400)

    def get_time(self):
        date_now = datetime.now().time()
        return str(date_now)

    def get_date(self):
        time_now = datetime.now().date()
        return str(time_now)

    def create_log_file(self): # save a log.txt file with the current date in name
        log_file_name = 'Log' + '_' + str(self.get_date()) + '.txt'
        with open(log_file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
            text_file.write(self.soup_class)
        return log_file_name

    def send_mail(self): # define mail contents / sender / receiver
        sender = "Sender <sender@example.com>"
        receiver = "Receiver <receiver@example.com>"

        message = f"""\
        Subject: test notification mail
        To: {receiver}
        From: {sender}

        This is a test e-mail notification."""

        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.example.com", 2525) as server:
            server.login("username", "password")
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

        print('Notification mail sent to:', receiver)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

Maybe someone knows what's wrong here.

The debuglevel output:

```
send: 'ehlo LAPTOP\r\n'
reply: b'250-smtp.example.com\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 5242880\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-DSN\r\n'
reply: b'250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5\r\n'
reply: b'250 STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'smtp.example.com\nSIZE 5242880\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nDSN\nAUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5\nSTARTTLS'
send: 'AUTH CRAM-MD5\r\n'
reply: b'334 MD5sum_removed==\r\n'
reply: retcode (334); Msg: b'MD5sum=='
send: 'MD5sum=\r\n'
reply: b'235 2.0.0 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: b'2.0.0 OK'
send: 'mail FROM:<sender@example.com> size=175\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.0 Ok'
send: 'rcpt TO:<receiver@example.com>\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.0 Ok'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354 Go ahead\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'Go ahead'
data: (354, b'Go ahead')
send: b'        Subject: test notification mail\r\n        To: Receiver <receiver@example.com>\r\n        From: Sender <sender@example.com>\r\n\r\n        This is a test e-mail notification.\r\n.\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.0.0 Ok: queued\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.0.0 Ok: queued'
data: (250, b'2.0.0 Ok: queued')
send: 'QUIT\r\n'
reply: b'221 2.0.0 Bye\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: b'2.0.0 Bye'
```

Comment: Is the message "Notification mail sent to..." printed?

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes it is, that is why I struggle to find the error.

Comment: try adding `server.set_debuglevel(1)` straight after the with clause and looking at the output.  maybe it's a problem on the mailserver (https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel)

Comment: Also double-check you really have got identical code in your `send_mail` function, and that it still works as a standalone script.  99% sure the mailserver's being funny or there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: Hmm..., you open a new SMTP session from the same address to the same server with the same credential in a loop. That is highly inefficient. The common way is to open a SMTP session and then loop sending messages.

Comment: @2e0byo I double checked the code and the standalone script works fine, also copied the code again into the main file, it is still not working tho. 
Also thought about the mail server, but all mails including the test mails from standalone arrive...

Comment: @SergeBallesta true, but it shouldn't fail all the same

Comment: @Criomby add the debuglevel line and post the output trace (obviously santising it)

Comment: @2e0byo I added the debuglevel output to the question above. 
It seems to queue the mail, but I do not understand why that is.

Comment: Could you do the same thing with the working script?  This is *weird* though

Comment: Hmm... In the *not working* example, the headers are preceded with spaces, which is not correct. You should try to remove those offending spaces from your multiline string `message`. Unsure that it is the cause, but it should be fixed anyway...

Comment: @2e0byo It is very strange. 
I have done the same with the working script, the output is exactly the same, but the mail is sent a couple seconds later, so the que seems to be working.

Comment: Your logs show successful delivery of the message (queueing is normal).  Unless there's some difference between the log of your successful and failed deliverie, something very odd is happening at the server level.  As @SergeBallesta notes, though, you shouldn't have spaces.

Comment: I think @SergeBallesta might have got it.  Due to the indented class it's the only difference between the code.  Whilst spaces before the headers are incorrect, it dounds like you've hit a bug in the server.

Comment: @2e0byo It is not a bug. the server receives an incorrect SMTP message and cannot process it. The body can contain almost anything (except for a line containing only a dot because it marks the end of the message), but the formatting of the headers part is much more precise.

Comment: @2e0byo I just had the same idea. This is the only difference.
I just tried to wrap the working script into a function and I get the same error, the script runs but no mail is sent. Outside of the function it works just fine.

Comment: @SergeBallesta How does a correct header look like? Would really appreciate an example, as I have made some changes according to you but it is still not working.
Is it just the spaces in the message part?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I stand corrected.  It would be handy if the server told us. (But ofc that's what standards are far, so it doesn't have to) Regadless, would you add an answer so this question can be closed?  And thanks: I learned something

Comment: @2e0byo: the problem is that SMTP is not an end to end protocol. The first server (receiving part) could correctly receive a message and stored it in the delivery queue. But then the next module is unable to process the message. The server admin has probably received a warning for the offending messages.

Comment: @SergeBallesta if you could provide an answer with the corrected code I would highly appreciate it, so I can see what it is supposed to look like and close the question with an answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer described by [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) solves the issue.

The indentation in the message string creates spaces which lead to a faulty message which cannot be processed further after received by the smtp server.

This is the right format:

```
def send_mail(self): # define mail contents / sender / receiver
        sender = "Sender <sender@example.com>"
        receiver = "Receiver <receiver@example.com>"

        message = f"""\
Subject: test notification mail
To: {receiver}
From: {sender}

This is a test e-mail notification."""

        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.example.com", 2525) as server:
            server.login("username", "password")
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

        print('Notification mail sent to:', receiver)
```